# React - one file app - Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components)

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a one file app with no import from other files and no webpack but I can not make it work as I get the message

'Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.'

and the message

Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

My file looks like this.

INDEX.HTML

In the head I have the following links

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15/dist/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-router@3.0.0/umd/ReactRouter.js"></script>
```

In the body I have the div with id="root" and the script tag with type "text/label" and then in the script tag the following code:

```
let BrowserRouter = ReactRouter.BrowserRouter;
  let Route = ReactRouter.Route;
  let Switch = ReactRouter.Switch;

  class FriendsIndexRoute extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
           some content
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <main>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={FriendsIndexRoute} />
        </Switch>
      </main>
    </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Any idea what is causing the issue?

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Is it because I do not do import React from 'react';
// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

Comment: Try removing each component one at a time to see which one causes your error. Start by removing the `<Route ... />` line and replace it with an empty div or something

Comment: thanks a lot. The errors stop only when I remove all the BrowserRouter 
Route and Switch elements (I tested one by one...)....Does it mean that I did not import them properly?

Comment: yeah, see El Aoutar Hamza's answer. You will need react-router-4 in order to use the Switch and the react-router-dom for the BrowserRouter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BrowserRouter` is a part of `react-router-dom`, so you need to add it to your scripts.

And `Switch` is in React router V4, so you will need to upgrade from V3 to V4.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5okau659/)